# Is app script long running in the background?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

clicking the run button. Will the script continue to run in the background after I close the browser tab? if not, any way to let it keep running?

Comment: You can answer that question for yourself by starting the script, closing the browser and returning later and looking at the executions to how long it ran.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Once you run it, it will continue to run even if the browser is closed. [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) is being run on Google's servers.

It halts when the script ends (success/fail) or reaches the limit of execution which is [6 minutes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).